# Drawing a straight line between 2 annotation on mapView

Tags: objective-c, mkmapview, mapkit

I have a mapView with 4 annotations.
I want to be able to draw a straight line (only straight) between the points. for example:
point 1 ----- point 2 ---- point 3 ----------- point 4;

Also I need the lines to be resized and scaled according to the map zoom and movement.

Is there any way to do so?

Comment: Did you try with a MKOverlayPathRenderer ?

Comment: Yes there is a way to do this. What have you tried. Surely searching on the internet you can find a way to dray a line on an MKMapView, so after trying that tell us what didn't work and someone will find a way to help you.